# ClrDateContainer receive in docker undefined commonStrings

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

We use submodules. From one times we started received error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '__source' of undefined

After debug code I founded that problem is commonString in ClrDateContainer component in undefinded

link for screenshots (I can't publish)
https://ibb.co/SyRRCHZ
https://ibb.co/gwQWW5R

With local build ok. It happens looks like only in docker.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail, such as a demo or source code. Also you probably should just use `ClarityModule` to avoid dependency issues (which might be happening here).

Comment: Looks like problem was in some old decencies. I updated clr ui to latest version and problem gone.